# Display seconds along with hours:minutes in Outlook message header

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have created a new column in the Inbox and Sent Items to display hours, minutes and seconds. How can display the values of this new column in the message header when I open the mail?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the internet header of the message or the message header where From, To, Subject fields show? To my knowledge, neither are possible. The internet headers are generated during the transfer process which we cannot control. It's also not possible to show the Hours, Minutes and Seconds time formatting on the header of the message. Hope I didn't misunderstand it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. By header I mean is that when you open the mail to read it you open a outlook message frame. This Outlook message frame has a header starting with e.g. Mo 20.11.2017 17:37 in the first line. Name of the sender in the second line, Subject in the 3rd line and the the name of the person to whom the mail was sent to in the fourth line.

Comment: I am trying to add the seconds in the first line. I created a new column indicidual column where I incleded seconds so it shows hrs:min:secons i this new added column of the mail list. I want the secons to appear on the first line of the message header as explained above., Thanks, TR

Comment: just realized many spelling misttakes, kindly excuse